# HttpUrlConnect not sending a post request as part of a thread

Tags: java, rest

I'm trying to send a http post request as part of a concurrent thread to an application launch.

The code below shows the current code I have now.  I tried using the code from Baeldung and similar tutorial sites but I can't seem to get this working.

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost:5000/").openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    String jsonInputString = "{\"status\": \"UP\"}";
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

    //random code here not involved with this quesiton

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        while (true) {
          try {

            os.write(jsonInputString.getBytes());
            os.flush();
        }
          catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Its not working");
          }
        }

      }
    }).start();
    launch(args);
```

When I go to type in localhost:5000 in a browser it says it can't connect.

Comment: No it doesn.'t. It throws an IOException with a specific message, and that isn't it. Your title doesn't agree with your question, and contains a spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

First step make sure local host is working on port 5000, go to http://localhost:5000/ in a regular browser, if thats not working you need to make sure your machine is serving a page on port 5000 properly.

If thats working, the HTTP request may be getting blocked because its not connecting to a server with a valid SSL certificate, you can try changing the webpage to http://www.google.com and see if it gets a response.